# how to access Yii2 grid view data

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have implement yii2 grid view in my application and I need to pass the grid view's selected output in to pdf printer when print the as  a report when I press the print button.
I have no idea how can I access the result-set of grid view and pass it to my controller action

I am using kartik mpdf extension for pdf generation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9K41.jpg

when I press print button I need to get the data in grid view and pass it into mpdf extension.

here is  part of my view file

```
<h5>Details of Education Qualification</h5>
<?php
echo Html::a('<i class="fa far fa-hand-point-up"></i> Print', ['/pdfrpt/report'], [
    'class'=>'btn btn-danger', 
    'target'=>'_blank', 
    'data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 
    'title'=>'Will open the generated PDF file in a new window'
]);
?>

<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'EmpNo',
        ['attribute'=> 'nameWithInitial',
          'label' => 'Name',
            'value' =>'empNo.nameWithInitial',],
```

and this is how I call pdf (report action in pdfrpt controller)

```
     public function actionReport() {
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE, 
            'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            'content' => $this->renderPartial('test'),// here  I need to specify current grid view data
            'options' => [

            ],
            'methods' => [
                'SetTitle' => 'Report title',
                'SetSubject' => 'Generating PDF files via yii2-mpdf extension has never been easy',
                'SetHeader' => ['report title||Generated On: ' . date("r")],
                'SetFooter' => ['|Page {PAGENO}|'],
                'SetAuthor' => '',
                'SetCreator' => '',
                'SetKeywords' => ' ',
            ]
        ]);
        return $pdf->render();
    }
```

Comment: what are you using for PDF generating like mPDF,fPDF,etc...

Comment: Also, can you show the code that generates the print button.

Comment: i am using kartik yii2-mpdf extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have use pagination false   other wise it will give data for first page.

```
  // create the data provider by configuring its pagination and sort properties
    $provider = new XyzDataProvider([
        'pagination' => [...],
        'sort' => [...],
    ]);

    // retrieves paginated and sorted data
    $models = $provider->getModels();

    // get the number of data items in the current page
    $count = $provider->getCount();

    // get the total number of data items across all pages
    $totalCount = $provider->getTotalCount();
```

Comment: I am using active dataprovider inside grid view and sort and pagination works inside gridview widget so how can I get current (filtered) content from outside it to send mpdf extention

Comment: after applying filter get that data using $models = $provider->getModels(); and store it in variable or session for temporary and send it to pdf .

Comment: thanks for helping i'll try it & hope it would work

Comment: is this possiable to access only paginatin UI?

Comment: No only data can access but you can create custom for that